# Cannot Access Properties of a Reporting Service Role

Tags: reporting-services

Our team has setup a Windows Server to specifically run SSRS in it. We have the reports running well but we wanted to manage several tasks under the Browser role to get rid of a couple of things. I believe this can be accessed through SSMS by logging in to the Report Server. I did this just fine but when I'm trying to open the properties of the Browser role, it is grayed out and can't be selected. Am I doing something wrong here?

A couple of notes to clear things out:

- I'm already using an admin account on the server
- The Reporting Server is installed separately to a source DB from which we get to access data
- I'm able to do this just fine when both Reporting Server and source DB are on the server
- I'm using SQL Server 2016 with the same version of SSRS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have figured it out. We just need to open SSMS as administrator. Might just be a user error of some sort as we do not need to do this on other servers. Thanks.